# how to take a snap shot from webcam with a flash interface on website?

Tags: flash, web, webcam

How to write/implement a program which takes images(any format png,jpg) from webcam and save it as images?

I need to implement that in webapplication, with Flash spport?

is there any tutorial for how to build an application like this.

Answer (score 1):

The basic technique is to first use Camera.get to grab the users webcam and then attach it to a Video object. Then, you create a BitmapData object and use it's draw method to capture a frame of the video. Finally you use the JPGEncoder class that's part of AS3CoreLIb (just google it) to convert the BitmapData object into a JPG stored in a ByteArray.

Comment: It wouldn't be Flash if it were straightforward and easy :)